# How to set R’s optim() starting values for a function that takes point coordinates?

Tags: r, optimization

I have built a simple function in R taking in four parameters. The four parameters are the coordinates of two points, `A` and `C`.

The function calculates a penalty based on the position of `A` and `C`.

I wonder what's the best way to build this function, *given that I will optimize it later* to find the point's coordinates that give me the minimum penalty.

Should I create a function that takes in the four parameters? See this toy example:

```r
simple_function1 <- function(x,y,z,w) {
  sum_coordinates <- sum(x+y) + sum(z+w)
  distance <- w-y
  penalty <- sum_coordinates + distance
  return(penalty)
}

simple_function1(0,1,0,0)
#> [1] 0
```

Or should I take in a function that takes in the two points' coordinates?

```r
pointA <- c(0,1)
pointC <- c(0,0)
simple_function2 <- function(A,C) {
  sum_coordinates <- sum(A[1]+A[2]) + sum(C[1]+C[2])
  distance <- C[2]-A[2]
  penalty <- sum_coordinates + distance
  return(penalty)
}
simple_function2(pointA,pointC)
#> [1] 0
```

After I create the function, I want to optimize it. I need to give starting values to `optim()`.

For example, if I try to optimize the first function, `simple_function1`:

```r
optim_output1 <- optim(par = c(0,0,0,0), # Applying optim
                       fn = simple_function1
)
```

I get an error:

```
#> Error in fn(par, ...): argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

The second version, `simple_function2`, makes more sense to me, but I don't know how to tell `optim()` what the starting values are.

I have tried:

```r
optim_output2 <- optim(par = c(c(0,0),c(0,0)), # Applying optim
                       fn = simple_function2
)
```

But I get a similar error:

```
#> Error in fn(par, ...): argument "C" is missing, with no default
```

Comment: Your function should pass the parameters via *one* argument, not 4 or 2.

Comment: Thank you @G.Grothendieck. Is that because I will later optimize the function? Could you please post an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66640006/how-can-i-minimize-this-function/66640449#66640449

Comment: You should specify the parameters in a way that makes sense for the most common use of it.  If it is *only* for use in `optim()`, use one vector parameter.  If other uses are important, write it to suit them, and when you want to optimize it, write a small "wrapper" function that accepts the arguments in the form `optim()` wants.

Comment: Thank you @user2554330, I had heard about the "wrapper" function and now I understand what it is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote my function so that it takes only one argument, a vector of four values:

```r
# create function
simple_function <- function(x) {
  xa <- x[1]
  ya <- x[2]
  xm <- x[3]
  ym <- x[4]
  sum_coordinates <- sum(xa+ya) + sum(xm+ym)
  distance <- ym - ya
  tot <- sum_coordinates + distance
  return(tot)
}
# the function takes a vector
vec <- c(1,1,0,0)
simple_function(vec)
#> [1] 1
```

Now `optim()` works:

```r
# optimizing the function
optim_output <- optim(par = c(0,0,0,0), # Applying optim
                       fn = simple_function
)
```

But it's even better to use a **wrapper function**:

```r
toy_function <- function(x,y,z,w) {
  sum_coordinates <- sum(x+y) + sum(z+w)
  distance <- w-y
  penalty <- sum_coordinates + distance
  return(penalty)
}

wrapper = function(args){
  toy_function(x = args[1],
                 y = args[2],
                 z = args[3],
                 w = args[4])
}

# the function takes a vector
vec <- c(1,1,0,0)
wrapper(vec)
#> [1] 1
#> [1] 1

  
# optimizing the function
optim_output <- optim(par = c(0,0,0,0), # Applying optim
                        fn = wrapper
  )

optim_output
#> $par
#> [1]  4.905791e+21  1.614870e+23 -2.644937e+22 -3.214087e+23
#> 
#> $value
#> [1] -6.64361e+23
#> 
#> $counts
#> function gradient 
#>      501       NA 
#> 
#> $convergence
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $message
#> NULL
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>